# WCF: "Cancel" operation Call Dependent on Request Message Contract

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, messagecontract, wcf-extensions

Here's my contract:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceContract {
    [OperationContract]
    OperationResponse1 Operation1(OperationRequest1 req);

    [OperationContract]
    OperationResponse2 Operation2(OperationRequest2 req);
    }
```

OperationRequest1 and OperationRequest2 both inherit from BaseOperationRequest, which holds credential information for all requests that come in to the service:

```
    [MessageContract]
public abstract class BaseOperationRequest {
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public Guid Token { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private User User { get; set; }
}
```

OperationResponse1 and OperationResponse2  both inherit from a base class too:

```
    [MessageContract]
public abstract class BaseOperationResponse {
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public ServiceErrors ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

ErrorCode is an enumeration.

As you can see on the request, I have two message headers, and one internal object that does not get deserialized as part of the SOAP message. The reason for this is that I want to inject this object in to the request *before* it is processed by my service implementation. Every single operation implementation will use this object, and I don't want each operation to make two calls to my data layer.

I would like to use WCF extensiblity (via an attribute) to perform two tasks:

1. Authenticate the requesting user.
2. Populate "User" on the incoming request class with a complex / composite business object, for use within every operation.

I've investigated IOperationInvoker, IDispatchMessageFormatter and IDispatchMessageInspector, but I've not found any of them to be quite suitable enough.

FYI, here's a primitive example implementation of my service, without any fancy WCF extensibility (or my repository / data layer calls):

```
public class MyService: IMyServiceContract {
    public OperationResponse1 Operation1(OperationRequest1 req) {
        if(req.Token == new Guid("GUID VALUE") && req.Password == "password") {
            // Perform some actions....

            return new OperationResponse1 {
                Success = true
            }
        } else {
            return new OperationResponse1 {
                Success = false,
                Error = "You are not authenticated"
            }
        }
    }
    public OperationResponse2 Operation2(OperationRequest2 req) {
        if(req.Token == new Guid("GUID VALUE") && req.Password == "password") {
            // Perform some actions....

            return new OperationResponse2 {
                Success = true
            }
        } else {
            return new OperationResponse2 {
                Success = false,
                Error = "You are not authenticated"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IOperationInvoker seems to be the most suitable extension point, but I can't quite figure out how to "cancel" the operation and override the response to the client. Here's where I got to:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides an invoker that can be used to authenticate a BaseOperationRequest message.
/// </summary>
public class UserAuthenticationInvoker : IOperationInvoker {
    /// <summary>
    /// The original operation invoker.
    /// </summary>
    private IOperationInvoker _originalInvoker;

    /// <summary>
    /// The injected User service, for authentication.
    /// </summary>
    [Inject]
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }


    public UserAuthenticationInvoker(IOperationInvoker originalInvoker) {
        _originalInvoker = originalInvoker;
    }

    #region Implementation of IOperationInvoker {

    public object[] AllocateInputs() {
        return _originalInvoker.AllocateInputs();
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs) {
        // Validate base request
        if(!(inputs[0] is BaseOperationRequest)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("The request object must inherit from BaseOperationRequest in order for User authentication to take place.");
        }

        // Get BaseOperationRequest
        var req = (BaseOperationRequest)inputs[0];

        // Authenticate the User
        var authResult = UserService.AuthenticateUser(new AuthenticateUserRequest {
            Token = req.Token,
            Password = req.Password
        });
        if(authResult.Success) {
            // This is where I get stuck - do I need to modify "outputs"? If so, how do I tell the invoker that I want a particular response to be returned, and to cancel the rest of the operation?
            return _originalInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, outputs);
        }
        return _originalInvoker.Invoke(instance, inputs, out outputs);
    }

    public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("The operation cannot be invoked asynchronously.");
    }

    public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("The operation cannot be invoked asynchronously.");
    }

    public bool IsSynchronous {
        get { return true; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered this myself. Ended up modifying the "input" to the _originalInvoker by implementing some dynamic types, and moving the injection to the attribute so I could mock / unit test the invoker. Here's my code:

**Attribute:**

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class AuthenticateUserAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior {
        #region Implementation of IOperationBehavior

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription) {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation) {
            // Manual injection
            var userService = NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Get<IUserService>();

            // Assign the custom authentication invoker, passing in the original operation invoker
            dispatchOperation.Invoker = new UserAuthenticationInvoker(dispatchOperation.Invoker, operationDescription.SyncMethod.ReturnType, userService);
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation) {
            throw new NotImplementedException("This behaviour cannot be applied to a server operation.");
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

**IOperationInvoker:**

```
public class UserAuthenticationInvoker : IOperationInvoker {
    /// <summary>
    ///     The original operation invoker.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IOperationInvoker _originalInvoker;

    private readonly Type _responseType;

    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public SupplierAuthenticationInvoker(IOperationInvoker originalInvoker, Type responseType, IUserService userService) {
        _originalInvoker = originalInvoker;
        _responseType = responseType;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    #region Implementation of IOperationInvoker {

    public object[] AllocateInputs() {
        return _originalInvoker.AllocateInputs();
    }

    public object Invoke(object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs) {
        // Validate base objects request
        if(!(inputs[0] is BaseOperationRequest)) throw new ArgumentException("The request object must inherit from BaseOperationRequest in order for user authentication to take place.");

        dynamic response = Activator.CreateInstance(_responseType);
        if(!(response is BaseOperationResponse)) throw new InvalidOperationException("The response object must inherit from BaseOperationResponsein order for user authentication to take place.");

        var req = (BaseOperationRequest)inputs[0];

        // Authenticate the user
        var authResult = _userService.AuthenticateUser(new AuthenticateUserRequest {
            Token = req.Token,
            Password = req.Password
        });

        if(!authResult.Success) {
            // Authentication failed, return reflected response object.
            outputs = new object[0];
            // Set response headers
            response.Success = false;
            response.ErrorCode = ServiceErrors.AuthErrorInvalidTokenOrPassword;

            return response;
        }
        // Authentication success, set the user and call the original method
        dynamic modifiedInput = inputs;
        modifiedInput[0].User = authResult.User;

        var invoked = _originalInvoker.Invoke(instance, modifiedInput, out outputs);

        return invoked;
    }

    public IAsyncResult InvokeBegin(object instance, object[] inputs, AsyncCallback callback, object state) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("The operation cannot be invoked asynchronously.");
    }

    public object InvokeEnd(object instance, out object[] outputs, IAsyncResult result) {
        throw new NotImplementedException("The operation cannot be invoked asynchronously.");
    }

    public bool IsSynchronous {
        get { return true; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Invoker is then applied to the service contract as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyServiceContract {
    [OperationContract]
    [AuthenticateUser]
    OperationResponse1 Operation1(OperationRequest1 req);

    [OperationContract]
    [AuthenticateUser]
    OperationResponse2 Operation2(OperationRequest2 req);
}
```